# Inherited member variable with specialized initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

Say we have a class that encapsulates a vector, like this:

```
class VectorContainer
{
    public:
        VectorContainer()
            : mVector()
    protected:
        std::vector<int> mVector;
};
```

Assume we have an inheritance structure in place making the only sensible constructor the one given above - **no more may be added.**

Say we need a specialized subclass of `VectorContainer` in which `mVector` represents a grid having predetermined, constant row/column count. Can we make a constructor akin to 
`DerivedContainer(size_t numRows, size_t numColumns)`while simultaneously initializing `mVector` to the proper size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the constructor for `VectorContainer`, you cannot achieve your objective. This is because this base constructor will always be called by the constructor of `DerivedContainer`, since this is the only ctor that exists. This is sensible encapsulating behaviour as well - `mVector` is a member of `VectorContainer` and it is `VectorContainer`s responsibility to properly construct it. `DerivedContainer`s constructor can always resize it as needed.

Comment: In other words: the most efficient, "C++ish" manner to have the described behavior is to let `VectorContainer` construct `mVector` and then call `mVector.resize(...)` within the `DerivedContainer` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Your member variable `mVector` is private, therefore nothing outside of `VectorContainer` can't access it. Since it is not possible to extend the `VectorContainer` class, it is useless.

---

For protected, you can create a constructor in derived class :

```
class DerivedContainer : VectorContainer
{
    public:
        DerivedContainer(size_t numRows, size_t numColumns) : VectorContainer()
        {
            mVector.assign( numRows );
        }
};
```

I am not sure why you pass two variables to constructor, but std::vector is one dimension array.

Comment: More for reading clarity than anything else - when representing a 3x3 grid, it makes sense to construct an instance in a way that looks like a 3x3 grid even though we know it has 9 elements.